# ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ssh, ftp, connection, sftp

I've got an odd and urgent problem. I'm trying to connect to a vendor's ftp site. I have tried connecting from multiple places. I've found that I cannot connect from my production server1 but I can connect from my testserver1 which are both housed in the same datacenter. I can also connect from the backup server located in another datacenter. I cannot connect from my office computer, but I can connect from my home computer. Up until about 2 days ago, I was able to connect on all of these boxes.

```
sftp -v username@host

Connecting to host...
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to host [**.**.**.**] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/***/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/***/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 2 keys
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

I'm able to successfully ping the host from all boxes. I've run traceroutes for all of them as well and it doesn't appear to be cutting off anywhere. I've been on the phone with the vendors network admin and she says that despite it saying connection established on my end, she doesn't see me connecting anywhere in the logs.

I've tried browsing some other similar questions but I'm not having any luck. If anyone can point me in the right direction or shed any light on the situation it would be greatly appreciated. I've tried turning off the firewall on my office machine and still no luck. We're not using keys so I'm not sure why they are loading. Where it is being reset is where it prompts me for my password on the machines where it works.

I'm also more than happy to call the vendor's customer service if it's something on their end.

*Update* 
adding -vvv gave me the line:
    debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
between the applying options and connecting to host lines.

Comment: Are there any entries in your /var/log/auth.log that might indicate what the potential problem is? Have you verified that your IP is not listed in iptables or perhaps hosts.deny?

Comment: Try more `-v`s and see if you get better debugging info? (`-vvv` is usually a good level for debugging funky problems)

Comment: @voretaq7 I tried -vvv but I didn't get any more information.

Comment: @KayakJim I assume this would all need to be checked on the host I'm trying to connect to, correct?

Comment: Yes, those log files are all contained on the host.

Comment: From the error message, you're failing to authenticate.  Also, you are may want to test if they're now blocking port 20, since you initiate the connection on port 22, then swap to 20 for authentication (or at least this is what I remember).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, we were able to get in touch with the vendor we were trying to connect to and their ISP. Their ISP watched and indeed they were, for whatever reason, closing our connection immediately.

Answer (score 0):

- check your firewall just for test do `service iptables stop` and try to connect again.
- try to ssh from the box to same box without going outside.

Answer (score 0):

Give the correct permissions for the keys, I think SSH will not read the keys if they don't have the correct permissions, those permissions are 0600.

Also, do you have a brute force detector such as denyhosts? If so, make sure you are in the whitelist. Also check the /etc/hosts.deny and /etc/hosts.allow files (this is at the server where you are trying to connect).

Comment: It will also not read the keys if the perms on the home directory are more permissive than 700.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turned out to be an ISP in Asia that was disrupting SSH connections. Using OpenVPN to a jump box elsewhere solves the temporary issue. If you bash your head against the wall trying to fix this, try a VPN link first and see if its transport related, rather than your config.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your SSH daemon, that could solve the problem.

I had the same issue and restarting the SSH service solved it by resetting it's security.

You can restart in WHM under Restart Services.